# FRR and FAR using python

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm

I have implemented SVM classifier and it gave me the predicted label. In here, I want to ask how to calculate FAR (False Acceptance Rate) and FRR (False Rejection Rate) from the results that is given by SVM. I have tried search in Google, but I cant find it.

Comment: You have not given much details. What kind of answers do you expect?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini my point is how we can obtain FAR and FRR, if we have the true label and predicted label using python :)

Comment: What you are asking is clear. The problem is that you are asking for new code, without showing your existing code, and without showing the attempts you made. How can I write code to interpret results from your SVM if I have no idea how such results look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Classification accuracy after recall and precision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35811446/classification-accuracy-after-recall-and-precision)